# How important is it to wait for CDAudioManager to be initialized? (and how to properly do the waiting?)

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

A shipping Cocos Denshion demo app includes this in the method that loads sounds:

`while ([CDAudioManager sharedManagerState] != kAMStateInitialised) {
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.1];
    }`

However, I've seen other tutorials that don't go to the effort to verify the audio manager is setup before loading sounds, so I'm wondering just how critical this step is.

If it *is* critical, I have read that the `NSThread` method mentioned here is actually not useful, that it merely pauses all activity in all classes in the app, thus if the audio manager was *not* setup when this `while` loop runs, that setup process would also be paused during this `sleep` method and thus there is really no benefit to sleeping in this particular way.

So I guess the two questions are:

1. For Cocos audio folks, do you wait for audio manager to verify setup before you load sounds?
2. For anyone, is what I've heard about `NSThread sleepForTimeInterval` correct? If so, I'm surprised it was included in any official CocosDenshion demo app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer with the help of the Cocos2d forum. It is no longer necessary to manually initialize CDAudioManager. It is initialized automatically the first time you call its singleton, sharedManager. The code in this question is older and no longer necessary with current versions of CocosDenshion.